# How to declare variable 'Id' from query in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simple-salesforce

```
print(sf.query(query=LVGisVda))
```

**Console**:

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'WWWW_AC_2__DU_ListedVehicle__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/WWWW_AC_2__DU_ListedVehicle__c/a019E00000EAsqzQAD')])), ('Id', '**a019E00000EAsqzQAD**')])])])
```

How to declare a019E00000EAsqzQAD as variable?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to set a variable named "Id" whose value is \*\*a019E00000EAsqzQAD\*\* (or a019E00000EAsqzQAD), based on the results of the query?

Comment: You can declare variables from strings using built-in `exec`, like this: `exec(" foo = 'bar' ")`. Does that help?

Comment: @N.Kern After I received the result of query, I want to use value from query (ex. a019E00000EAsqzQAD), that's why I need to declare it.
But I have problem to wright proper code to take it from query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/) you can understand better what is an OrderedDict. 
But you can get the value wanted using:

```py
ordered_dict = sf.query(query=LVGisVda)
id_value = ordered_dict['records'][0]['Id']
```

In case you want to handle all data inside `ordered_dict['records']` you should consider loop through it, like:

```py
ordered_dict = sf.query(query=LVGisVda)
ids = [element['Id'] for element in ordered_dict['records']]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Test1\AC-7008.py", line 27, in <module>
    LV = sf.query(query=LVGisVda)['Id']
KeyError: 'Id'

Comment: nope, you should use `LV = sf.query(query=LVGisVda)['records'][0]['Id']`. Because the key `Id` is inside `records`.

Comment: @DmytroGordon you should also notice that `records` is a list and can contain N elements. Check if this use case is relevant for you. In my solution you are just picking the first element.

Comment: @DmytroGordon had you have the chance to check this out?